# jwplayer, oncomplete not working for `a` tag visibility

Tags: javascript, jwplayer6

The following code not working for the visibility of `a` tag.

```
events: {
onComplete: function() {
var x= document.getelementbyid("aID");
x.style.visibility = "hidden";
}       
}
```

But the event is fired well when the body of the javascript function is

```
onComplete: function() {
alert(x.innerHTML )}
```

Please help.

Comment: have you tried x.style.display='none' ?

Comment: As far as I know, the a tag does not support the event 'onComplete'. At the other hand the img tag does support it

Comment: Mr. K D. 'none is not working'

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
events: {
     onComplete: function() {
     var x= document.getElementById("aID");
     x.style.visibility = "hidden";
   }       
};
```

**getElementById** You wrote it wrongly. Use correct casing

Comment: Sorry, that is no helping. JavaScript is case sensitive. getElementById is not working.